# invoking an awk script in different ways

Tags: awk

I wrote an `awk` script called `c_awk.awk` and want to invoke like `awk -f c_awk.awk file.csv`.

The script looks like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     NR==FNR && 
     $7{sum+=$7; 
     elementos++; 
     next}
     !$7{$7=media}
     {print}
     ENDFILE{media=sum/elementos}' train.csv train.csv
```

The file works when doing copy-paste in the terminal.
By executing it: `gawk -f c_awk.awk`, an error occurs:

```
gawk: c_awk.awk:4: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
gawk: c_awk.awk:4:     ^ carácter «'» inválido en la expresión
gawk: c_awk.awk:4: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
gawk: c_awk.awk:4:     ^ syntax error
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong.
Could you help me?

The file which is called is the following: (train.csv from Kaggle, Titanic)

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
```

Thanks.

Comment: `copy-paste in the terminal. By executing it: gawk -f c_awk.awk` Your terminal is running a shell, not `gawk`. You can run `sh c_awk.awk`, or you can replace the file with the awk script only.

Comment: IOW, if you execute `gawk -f ...`, you should delete `awk` and the outer single quotes in the file

Comment: @KamilCuk, I tried ```sh c_awk.awk``` and it doesn't work. Any way, I need to execute the script as shown in the question (I editted due to my failure, sorry): ```gawk -f c_awk.awk fil.csv```

Comment: @WilliamPursell, where do you mean 'outer single quotes?'

Comment: Your script currently looks like `awk '{program to awk}'`.  By 'outer single quotes', I meant that it should just be `{program to awk}` if you intend to invoke it with `gawk`.  (You also need to remove the input file from the script and do `gawk -f program-file < input-file`)

Answer (score 1):

GNU `AWK` manual regarding [Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html) states that

```
-f source-file
--file source-file
```

> Read the awk program source from source-file instead of in the first nonoption argument. This option may be given multiple times; the
> awk program consists of the concatenation of the contents of each
> specified source-file.(...)

So selected file should hold only *source* not whole command. Simple example, let say you want to get 1st column, then you might create `firstcol.awk` with following content

```
{print $1}
```

and use it as follows

```
awk -f firstcol.awk file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Optionally you might elect to equip file with shebang and make it executable, in which case `firstcol.awk` content is

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{print $1}
```

and usage is

```
./firstcol.awk file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Consult [AWK in Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AWK) if you want to see other examples.

Comment: I tried with shebang and execution you told but still doesn't work. ```awk -f c_awk.awk train.csv```

Answer (score -1):

The solution consisted on following changes:

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     NR==FNR && 
     $7{sum+=$7; 
     elementos++; 
     next}
     !$7{$7=media}
     {print}
     ENDFILE{media=sum/elementos}
```